# Processing MOD35 cloud mask image?

Tags: image, modis

I have a question about processing MOD35 cloud mask image.

I worked reprojection on MOD35 cloud mask image using MODIS Swath Tool.

The processed results of MOD35 cloud mask are consist of 6 band images (band0, band1, band2, band3, band4, band5).

And each band images is 255 bits.

I know that MOD35 cloud mask images is 48bit having a lot of information about clouds(1-2 : unobstructed FOV donfidence flag, 5bit : snow/ Ice background Flag, 9bit : thin cirrus dected ).

what are the meaning of the band 0 to band 6 of processed result of MOD35 ?

Is it right that create 48 bit image using all bands (band 0 to band 6)?

I want to extract information from MOD35 cloud mask about  (1-2 : unobstructed FOV donfidence flag, 5bit : snow/ Ice background Flag, 9bit : thin cirrus dected).

How should handle this image?

Comment: Each band is *255* bits??? That's a very unusual number. Are you sure you aren't mistakenly reading the bands as 8 bit, with values between 0 and 255?